# Microsoft Azure Linux VM always having high CPU usage 24h/day even without any users

Tags: php, linux, azure, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

I have a VM running on Azure with a PHP script that may invoke the VM should it be activated. 
I don't know if it's a technical issue to deal with my code or something else, but even after days with no requests of any services to the VM i.e. no calls made to the PHP script, the Azure VM CPU keeps running at 97% for 24h/day and I cannot explain it myself as my usage is supposed to be based on each call to the VM services and not continuously operating at max CPU all the time.

What does it seems to you?

Comment: Which tire of VM service you are using? Do you have any task running on your VM? And do you have any result as @dgiard said run `top` in cmdlet?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux "top" command should tell you what processes are using the most CPU. This article explains how to use it: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html